# CPU scheduling for callback associated to dpdk rte_timer_reset()

Tags: dpdk

How is the callback execution scheduled on a lcore for the callback associated to rte_timer_reset() - If the dpdk app was already using the lcore to do other processing, how the timer callback scheduling work on that lcore?

Answer (score 1):

DPDK [does not support a scheduler](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/prog_guide/overview.html), only polling.

When you use Timer objects, you have to periodically call [rte_timer_manage()](https://doc.dpdk.org/api/rte__timer_8h.html#aad81303c11541adfb88c62c47b863fa6), to check for expired timers and call their associated callback functions.  In the [example Timer application](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/sample_app_ug/timer.html), they start a `mainloop` on each lcore and in that `mainloop`, they periodically call `rte_timer_manage`.

If you look at the code for `rte_timer_manage`, you can see that it builds a list (from the internal skip list data structure) and [calls each callback](https://github.com/DPDK/dpdk/blob/main/lib/timer/rte_timer.c#L733) function sequentially, but only for those timers running [on its own lcore id](https://github.com/DPDK/dpdk/blob/main/lib/timer/rte_timer.c#L660).